# Live data using HTTPWebRequest

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How do I get live (continuous) data from server in C#?

I open HTTPWebRequest but server doesn't complete that request, server sends some text data for every 20 seconds and I want to handle the text data and display to user after 10 minutes server completes the request.

Comment: That's not how HTTP is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is not a session protocol. It was meant to work like this

1. Open connection
2. Send request
3. Receive response
4. Close connection

What you can do is basically  Use `TCPClient / Socket` instead, which moves you to the layer lower that HTTP and allows you to create persistent connections.

There is variety of frameworks that will make your life easier.

Also, you might want to have a look at [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).

Comment: That's not quite true. There are APIs that support streaming. For example Twitter does that. See my answer for an example of how you could consume such an API.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the streaming API of a WebClient:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.OpenReadCompleted += (sender, args) =>
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(args.Result))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            // do something with the result
            // don't forget that this callback
            // is not invoked on the main UI thread so make
            // sure you marshal any calls to the UI thread if you 
            // intend to update your UI here.

        }
    }
};
client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://example.com"));
```

And here's a full example with the Twitter Streaming API:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "secret");
        client.OpenReadCompleted += (sender, args) =>
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(args.Result))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        };
        client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will `OpenREadCompleted` fire every time it has a portion of data? Cool.

Comment: No, it won't open everytime. There's onlty a single HTTP request for which the server is streaming the response. The server doesn't send a `Content-Length` response header and streams to the output socket.

Comment: The open read completed when the total request is completed but I want partially.

Comment: This means that your server is not using a Streaming API and is setting the `Content-Length` response header. There's not much you could do in this case.